# What is the name for the Tab button in nautilus's "accels" file?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, nautilus

I'm trying trying to customize nautilus's keyboard shortcuts, which I found can be changed through the `~/.config/nautilus/accels` file. I've successfully changed deleting file from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to just pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>, but I can't find out how to change tabs using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUpp</kbd>. I think it's because I can't figure out the name of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is labeled `<Primary>`).

I've tried searching for the answer, but couldn't find anything. If anyone could help me out, or at least point me in the direction of some relevant documentation that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really old question, but for any googlers looking for this: The name for <kbd>Tab</kbd> is Tab. But you can't use it for Nautilus accels, as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043328/871821) answer explains.

You can normally change a shortcut by uncommenting and modifying the relevant line in `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and restarting nautilus. Shortcuts that use the Tab key don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> in accels through an alternative interface (Python bindings). See [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035845/how-can-i-change-the-keybindings-in-nautilus/1209754#1209754) from the same thread blackbeard linked to.